# Hyperlinking FindBugs report to source code

Tags: java

By default, the HTML report generated by [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) specifies the name of the Java class and  line number(s) of each issue it reports.  Is there a way to tell FindBugs to hyperlink the report to the corresponding source code?  So far a search of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=findbugs%20hyperlink%20java%20source%20report%20output) and Google has not turned up any solutions.

Note that I am looking for an HTML solution as opposed to something that plugs into an IDE such as Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [FindBugs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin) plugin, [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) will serve up a nicely formatted report with hyperlinks to source code.  I do not know whether you can request a standalone copy of that report from Jenkins.